# libCodePush.a not found during Xcode archive

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I keep running into issues with React Native CodePush, during the Archive Process in Xcode. I am struggling with it creating a CodePush folder in

`/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CodePush/libCodePush.a`

but looking for the libCodePush.a file in

`/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCodePush.a`

This issue or a duplicate symbols issue i.e.

`ld: 230 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64`

are preventing me from finishing the archive process and I can't seem to track down the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*you should try deleting `codePush.xcodeproj` from your project navigator and manually linking it again.*

*you can try steps provided in `Plugin Installation (iOS - Manual)` section of below link.*

[*Plugin Installation (iOS - Manual)*](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md)